# How do you view all the cached versions of a web page?

Tags: cached-webpages

I was wondering if there is anyway to view an older cached version of a website than the one that shows up when you click "cached" on Google.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) from Archive.org.  Archive.org has been crawling the web for a long time, saving pages.

In the top center box is the Wayback Machine. Put the URL you want to view there (note the `http://` is already there) and if it has taken any snapshots, you will see a timeline at the top of the page showing you what dates it has.

I find about ¾ of the webpages I'm looking for.

Comment: Wikipedia has useful bookmarklets accessing archive.org's Wayback Machine [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Using_the_Wayback_Machine#JavaScript_bookmarklet)

Answer (score 2):

I have created good alternative website to Archive org cache check- https://cachearchive.com. Try it, it is easy to check Google cache with it also.

Comment: This is a great site and thanks for making it. However, this still shows the most recent cached version from Google cache. Isn't there a syntax you can use in the URL, particularly when you know the date of a previous cache that may exist?